# Redirecting with React-router if user is not authenticated

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, react-router

I'm building a React application with React-router and redux, and i have a profile page I want to show at `/profile` only if the user is authenticated. In my `App` component's `componentWillMount` method I am fetching the current user with `fetchUser()` which uses `axios` to send a `GET request` to my Express API. My `fetchUser()` returns `null` by default, and returns `false` or the `user object` when the request finishes. In my `Profile` component, I am trying to switch over the user (`null`, `false` or `user which should be truthy`). The problem I am facing is that my switch case gets called *before* the `fetchUser()` request comes through, and so the user is `null`. The following code gets the job done, but chrome throws an error in the console:

```
render() {
    if (this.props.auth === false) this.props.history.push('/');
    return (
        <div className="profile-page">
            //Profile page goes here
        </div>
    )
}
```

Error thrown by chrome:

```
Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within render or another component's constructor). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state; constructor side-effects are an anti-pattern, but can be moved to `componentWillMount`.
```

Just to clarify: The code works perfectly, but chrome still complains.
I realise this means I need to move my logic from from the `render` method into `componentWillMount` or `componentDidMount`. The problem is that when those lifecycle methods are called, the user object is null, and so that won't work (I've tried). Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You probably want to put it inside [`componentWillReceiveProps`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops).

Comment: This didn't work, but you sparked the thought in my mind that I could use the Update() lifecycle methods. Putting the logic into the componentDidUpdate() method solved the issue. Thanks anyway! I will answer my own question.

Comment: https://github.com/mjrussell/redux-auth-wrapper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the logic into the componentDidUpdate() lifecycle method solved the issue:

```
componentDidUpdate() {
        if (this.props.auth === false) return this.props.history.push('/');
    }
    render() {

        return (
            <div className="profile-page">
                <h4>Profile page</h4>
                <ProfileForm />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have observed correctly that render method should not contain any logic that is switching the state/rerouting.

If your fetchUser function is asyc then you should only render the component based on the response of fetchUser.

```
componentWillMount(){
      this.setState({loading:true})
      fetchUser().then( () =>{this.setState({auht:true,loading:false)}) 
            .catch( ()=>{this.setState({auth:false,loading:false})})
}
```

now based on **this.state.loading** you may take some decisions in the render.

Hope this works.

Comment: Just a quick question: Is there any reason your solution is better than mine (mine is far less code)? I'm a newbie when it comes to React, and I want to enforce best practices in my code, so if your code is somehow better than mine, than I'd really appreciate it if you could tell me why :)

Comment: Your code solves the developers problem but not browsers. My code make sense  only when fetchuser is async.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this? I'm sorry but I don't u understand what you mean by this. If you mean the chrome warning, then that did indeed go away when I used componentDidUpdate